# Detect the Position of the Last Object in a Loop Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script below spawn 20 objects on the Y axis, how can I get the Y position of the last object in this loop?

**Script:**

```
public GameObject[] Bricks;

void SpawnBricks(int numCubes = 20, float startY = 3, float delta = 0.6f, float AngleDis = 3f)
{
    int Rand = Random.Range(0, Bricks.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i)
    {
        var Brick = Instantiate(Bricks[Rand], new Vector3(0, startY - (float)i * delta, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Brick.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: add an if statement to see if `i + 1 = numCubes` if it returns true then its the last loop so then get `Brick.transform.position.y`

Comment: @CoderJoe It gives me the Y position of the object number 15, not number 20!

Comment: Can you add more detail into your question with what you have tried based on what you have I dont see an issue

Comment: @CoderJoe I solved the issue by adding "- delta*5" to the Y position.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the declaration of `Brick` outside the loop so it remains in scope after the loop exits, holding the last value assigned in the loop:

```
public GameObject[] Bricks;

void SpawnBricks(int numCubes = 20, float startY = 3, float delta = 0.6f, float AngleDis = 3f)
{
    GameObject Brick;

    int Rand = Random.Range(0, Bricks.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i)
    {
        Brick = Instantiate(Bricks[Rand], new Vector3(0, startY - (float)i * delta, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Brick.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }

    // Brick now holds the last object returned from Instantiate in the loop
}
```

Comment: It still gives the Y position of the object number 15, not number 20!

Comment: What is object number 15? Is that `Bricks[15]`? How is `Bricks` getting populated? You will need to provide more details. My best _guess_ at this point is that you are seeding `Random` with the same seed, and it just happens that 15 is the 20th random number in your case.

Comment: object number 20 is the last object spawned in the loop, and this code gives me every time the Y position of the 15th object in the loop, but I solved that by adding "- delta*5" to the Y position. Thanks!

Comment: I can promise you that the code I presented does in fact give you the last object returned from `Instantiate`. The problem is, I think, that you are accessing your `Bricks` array randomly. I assume it is being initialized elsewhere, and if what you really want is the 20th object from that, you can get that with `Brick = Bricks[19]` If you can more clearly explain in your original question what exactly you are trying to achieve I can modify my answer so that it will be helpful for future visitors.